# Change event in access won't work when cycling through records

Tags: vba, ms-access, events, subforms

I currently have a form with two sub-forms, In one sub-form called Customer Addresses I have a textbox that contains the address table primary key. I put buttons on this form to cycle to next or previous records, and when I cycle through these records I can see my different address Ids cycling in the text box.

Now when my addressIDs are being cycled I want that value to automatically update another textbox in another sub-form called CustomerContacts. I added some code to the change and the update events but had no success.

```
Private Sub Text0_Change()
        Me.Parent!ContactInformation.Form!ContactInformation_Address.Value = Text0.Value

End Sub
```

The references in the above code are correct. I tested this code with a combobox in which I actually hit the drop down arrow and selected a value and it successfully updated the other text box in the other subform.

So there is something I am missing here, when cycling through the records it will not trigger the change or the update events, so I am wondering how I can get around all this.

Comment: is the code in the userform's module?

Comment: yes it is, it is in the Customers address form, which is a sub-form. The above code works if I manually change the values by hand but won't work if I am just cycling through the records.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "cycling through"? are you changing a value programatically? If so we need to see the code that's doing the "change"

Comment: I am using command buttons with pre built macros one button will select the next record and the other will select the previous record.

Comment: I figured it out, I Converted the forms macors to visual basic so now my record selection button code is in vba. Then I just took my above code and put it below the line that changes the record.

Comment: Converted from what?

Comment: I converted a pre built macro to vba so I could edit it in the vba editor. When the I place a command button on the form in design view It comes up with a control wizard, I selected I pre built macro from the list of options to select my records in my form. You cant edit these macros in vba until they are converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted Forms macros to visual basic. Now my commands buttons that were selecting the next and previous records are in vba code. Next Take the code for the text box you want updated and put it under the line that selects the records.

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Command24_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Command24_Click()
On Error GoTo Command24_Click_Err

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acPrevious
    Me.Parent!ContactInformation.Form!ContactInformation_Address.Value = Text0.Value
    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If


Command24_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command24_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command24_Click_Exit

End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------
' Command25_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Command25_Click()
On Error GoTo Command25_Click_Err

    ' _AXL:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
    ' <UserInterfaceMacro For="Command24" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application"><Statements><Action Name="OnError"/><Action Name="GoToRecord"><Argument Name
    ' _AXL:="Record">Previous</Argument></Action><ConditionalBlock><If><Condition>[MacroError]&lt;&gt;0</Condition><Statements><Action Name="MessageBox"><Argument Name="Message">=[MacroError].[Description]</Argument></Action></Statements></If></ConditionalBlo
    ' _AXL:ck></Statements></UserInterfaceMacro>
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNext
    Me.Parent!ContactInformation.Form!ContactInformation_Address.Value = Text0.Value
    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If


Command25_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command25_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command25_Click_Exit

End Sub
```